# Does void(*) in C++ mean anything?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, void

I'm trying understand C++ function pointer syntax. In Eclipse on Linux when I typed:

```
void(*);
```

It highlighted the statement with a message saying syntax error, but it let me compile it and the program ran. Then on Visual Studio I tried it and it won't compile, saying "Expected an expression". However what's strange is that when I do:

```
std::vector<void(*)> myVector;
```

It compiles fine on Visual Studio. Also on a couple of online compilers void(*); on its own works fine. I know that:

```
void (*)();
```

... is a function pointer and..

```
void();
```

... is a function signature, which is why you can do:

```
std::function<void()> func;
```

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding function pointer syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: What compiler accepts `void (*);` ?

Comment: This one: https://ideone.com/lEeMY3, and http://www.cpp.sh/  but this one doesn't http://codepad.org/Zl1UQRa3. Visual Studio will accept it in the std::vector declaration/definition. Strangely in Eclipse with GCC it highlights it as an error but still compiles and runs.

Comment: It sounds like a compiler bug or language extension, or a combination. I suggest you try out g++ with and without `-pedantic-errors` flag. With Ideone the statement `int(**);` compiles, but e.g. `int;`  or, in particular, `int**;`, does not compile.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice ideone suppresses a lot of the underlying compiler's error messages, it's not really good for anything.  Eclipse is an IDE, not a compiler. You should mention exactly which version of gcc and which switches were used; all the versions I tried of gcc gave an error in their default mode for `void (*);` .

Comment: `std::vector<void(*)> myVector;` is correct, please note that I am asking about `void (*);` by itself which is an error. (In the same way that `vector<int> myVector;` is correct and `int;` is not).

Comment: @M.M try it at block scope.

Comment: @M.M In Linux I was running Eclipse compiling with GCC. Sorry I don't know what switches, I'm new to Linux. What I thought was strange was that it highlighted it saying it was a syntax error, but it still compiled and ran. I thought syntax error was a pretty serious error.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice it is a pretty serious error. Nobody can reproduce your alleged "still compiled and ran" so the best we can say is either there was a compiler bug, or it didn't actually compile and run but you thought it did.

Comment: Reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78928

Answer (score 12):

Remember that parentheses can be used to change the precedence of certain things. That's why you have the parentheses around the asterisk in `void (*)()` because it's very different from `void *()`.

In the case of `void(*)` the parentheses are such precedence-changing parentheses. But they are not needed. The type `void(*)` is `void*`, plain and simple.

The *context* where you use it is important though.

Comment: It's interesting, because if the parentheses are just a precedence thing and it means the same thing, it's strange that on two online compilers I tried, if I take off the parentheses it won't compile.

Comment: This hypothesis (the answer at the time I'm writing this) does not match the fact that with Ideone `void(*);` compiles but `void*;` does not. It's fine as far as it goes but it provides no explanation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That portion is just a compiler bug.

Comment: @T.C. The same thing happened on another compiler I tried. void( * ); complained, but void*; was fine. Well I'm chalking this one up to parentheses precedence, anyway.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice What compiler?